# Can I import a source folder from Eclipse into Flash Builder?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, flash, builder

I have the source folder from a friend's Android app and I am going to do all of the design for the app. If I could import the folder that he gave me from Eclipse, it would be easier to create a nice UI for the app.

Is this possible? If not, can I load the XML files into Flash Builder to make the UI?

**EDIT:** To clarify, I have a project file that I can open in Eclipse. I want to edit the appearance of the project using Flash Builder without interfering with the application's functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely understanding if the first part is asking to import it back into Eclipse, if this is the case, then yes you can.

You can go about this by opening up Eclipse, then go to File > Import... > General > Existing Projects into Workspace. Once in there, you need to navigate to the source folder's location and click on the folder containing all of your project (bin, res, assets, gen, etc.) and then you should see a project appear in the window below the browse buttons. Make sure to check (click) the project you want to import and hit finish.

It should appear in your workspace now in Eclipse.

You can then just treat it as a normal project.

Comment: I have a project file that I can open in eclipse. I want to edit the appearance of the project using Flash Builder without interfering with the application's functionality.